# Antonym of "not"

Tags: antonyms

Now do you say that something is not *not* with a separate word after 'is'? It should sound as if you're correcting someone.

E.g.

- Negative: "He is *not* an idiot"
- Neutral: "He is an idiot"
- Affirmative: "He is *<insert word here?>* an idiot"

I can't insert "certainly" because that makes it slightly different: it doesn't sound like you're correcting someone.

For example, in Dutch, it goes like this:

- Negative: "Hij is *niet* een idioot"
- Neutral: "Hij is een idioot"
- Affirmative: "Hij is *wel* een idioot"

here, 'wel' and 'niet' are [complementary antonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_(semantics)#Complementary_antonyms).

And in Japanese:

- 彼がバカでは*ない*。
- 彼がバカです。
- 彼がバカです*よ*。 (the よ is a special 'convince' particle)

I'm aware that the English neutral variant sounds affirmative when the 'is' is stressed in speech. What would be the closest equivalent of the affirmative variant in plain-text writing (i.e. no italics/bold/etc allowed)? Surely English, as a widespread language, must have something similar?

I'm looking either for the complementary antonym of 'not' or another grammatical trick that conveys convincement.

Comment: I'd say *indeed* just to fill the need.

Comment: The word you want is ***so***. In fact, in Perl6, they deliberately introduced the keyword `so` as havjng opposite semantics to the standard `not`.

Comment: Children can sometimes be heard arguing "Is not!" "Is too!" "Is not!" "Is too!". It needs stress on the "too", and sounds childish. "He is too an idiot" would probably be understood, but it doesn't quite sound right to me.

Comment: I don't see how *He is an idiot* is "neutral."  It is not neutral. It has taken a stance.

Comment: @DanBron  "He is so an idiot." Hm... the *so* is not a "filler/ dummy" but an enhancer of the qualifier *cf.* "It's so nice."  Although: "that's so not fair" (**informal**). https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/so

Comment: Why the down vote?!

Comment: @Clare I'm afraid you didn't read it right in the first place.

Comment: See also: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/so